# Can not generate openaplr.framework in mac by using OpenALPR library

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, iphone, openalpr

I am using **https://github.com/twelve17/openalpr-ios** this library to analyse license plate images and get license number from it.

when i try to run ruby script in mac to generate **openaplr.framework** it gives me error.

This is the error i am getting.

> "/Volumes/DATA/Project_Stuff/openalpr-ios/lib/alpr/utils.rb:44:in
>   execute': Child returned: pid 587 exit 1 (RuntimeError) from
>   /Volumes/DATA/Project_Stuff/openalpr-ios/lib/alpr/utils.rb:74:inlog_execute'
>   from
>   /Volumes/DATA/Project_Stuff/openalpr-ios/lib/alpr/package/automake.rb:141:in
>   do_autoconf_build' from
>   /Volumes/DATA/Project_Stuff/openalpr-ios/lib/alpr/package/automake.rb:58:inbuild_arch'
>   from
>   /Volumes/DATA/Project_Stuff/openalpr-ios/lib/alpr/package/base.rb:53:in
>   block in install' from
>   /Volumes/DATA/Project_Stuff/openalpr-ios/lib/alpr/package/base.rb:52:ineach'
>   from
>   /Volumes/DATA/Project_Stuff/openalpr-ios/lib/alpr/package/base.rb:52:in
>   install' from ./bin/build_frameworks.rb:53:in

Thanks.

Comment: Which ruby version you are using ?

Comment: I am using git version = 2.6.4.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it by comment line:

```
#opts[:exit_on_error] = true if !opts.has_key?(:exit_on_error)
```

in file utils.rb line number 24.

System Mac OSX10.10, xCode7.2.1

Comment: Can u pls provide me openalpr framework which you have

Comment: I get Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/burfies1/openalpr/openalpr-ios/work/tesseract-3.03/api/apitypes.h when i pipe out that line